# Empty title on front page/Home

Tags: title

My main problem is around the title.  In my index.php, I have specified a title tag and inserted the following:

```
<?php wp_title(); ?> | <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
```

My problem is the it is only printing the blog "name" -  wp_title() prints nothing

i.e. This is what is being printed from the above:

> | Wordpress Test Site

NOTE: The Page Title should be: Home

Strangely, when I visit My Sample Page, it presents the following:

> » Sample Page | Wordpress Test Site

And they are both using the same header.php file!

Am I missing a setup somewhere that doesn't work on the home page?

FYI - I've set the Page - Home as the static front page.

Thanks

Comment: Here is better explanation from czerspalace.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178455/blank-title-on-static-home-page?newreg=18950e40d69f4fecaaaf8a70c3ddf1ea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title is empty at the front page in WordPress. Yes, that sucks.
Just put the separator into `wp_title()`:

```
<title><?php
//        separator, print immediately, separator position
wp_title( '·',       TRUE,              'right' );
bloginfo( 'name' );
?></title>
```

This prints out just the blog name on the front page and `PAGE NAME · BLOG NAME` on other pages.

Comment: thanks - I also looked into the function is_home() to print a static title

Comment: `is_home()` fails sometimes on multisite installs. Not reliable. :(

Comment: actually, is_home() doesn't work - is_front_page() is the ticket!

Comment: Same problem on multisite. For a breadcrumb plugin I wrote recently I had to hack around this bug.

Comment: thanks for feedback - this is a single basic site so should be ok