# Blank <title> on static home page?

Tags: php, templates, html, title

The `<title>` of each page on my site shows correctly with the following code:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

But on my home page, which is set to a static page called 'Home', the `<title>` attribute is blank. The HTML for 'Home' page looks like this:

```
<title></title>
```

The settings for the 'Home' page has 'Home' as the page title, but it doesn't show on the actual page output. Any idea why? The issue can be seen [here](https://www.dcturano.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title#Covering_Homepage)

`If you are using a custom homepage with custom loops and stuff or a custom front-page, you will have an empty wp_title. Here goes a neat hack to add the description/tagline at the wp_title place on homepage:`

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'baw_hack_wp_title_for_home' );
function baw_hack_wp_title_for_home( $title )
{
  if( empty( $title ) && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
    return __( 'Home', 'theme_domain' ) . ' | ' . get_bloginfo( 'description' );
  }
  return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, place it in header.php:

```
<title><?php wp_title('');?><?php if(is_front_page()) {bloginfo('name');}?></title>
```