# Front page displays different <title> than all other pages?

Tags: title

```
<head>
<title>
    <?php wp_title(''); ?>
</title>
</head>
```

This displays the page title in the title correctly everywhere except on the front page where it displays "Home | Motto...". How can I have the front page display the page title like it does everywhere else on the site?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Are you developing a theme? Are you using any plugins, especially SEO plugins? Are different templates being used? Are you calling wp_title() exactly the same way? This may help too: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43619/empty-title-on-front-page-home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure how is your title on other pages, but here is how you can modify your title:

`<?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>`

This will show your Blog's name right to your page's title, which will have seo benefits. The `|` separator will be used here.

If you want to customize your title further, you can use a situational `if()`, as the following:

`<title> <?php if ( is_home() ) { //Your custom title here } else { wp_title(''); } ?> </title>`

For custom title, you can use the following outputs:

`bloginfo('name')` =  Displays the “Site Title” set in Settings > General

`bloginfo('description')` = Displays the “Tagline” set in Settings > General

Or you can simply type your desired title in text format.

Answer (score 0):

why not replacing `wp_title` with `add_theme_support` function with '`title-tag`' parameter. this method is more convenient then the other.  maybe it'll help you.

```
function wpse_1012_setup() {

 add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_1012_setup' );
```

remove the title tag from head section and if `wp_head` is present in `header.php` then the page title should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place a if around your wp_title function like this :

```
<head>
<title>
    <?php 
    if (is_home()){
        echo 'Your home title';
    } else {
        wp_title();
    }
    ?>
</title>
</head>
```

Or the right way to do it would be to apply a filter on the title to alter it by placing this code in function.php.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'generate_custom_title', 900 );
function generate_custom_title($title) {
     if (is_home()) {
        $title = "Your title here";
     } 
     return $title;
}
```

if you do use Yoast plugin for SEO, you can also add this line to apply title to the Yoast meta titles

```
 add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'generate_custom_title', 900);
```

Comment: the_title hook is not deprecated. And it hasn't been removed since 4.4. It's right there in 4.7 -> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L158

Comment: See also this trac ticket: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35253

Comment: thanks for the clarification about the_title hook that i didnt checked much deeper then got code not working, found numbers of post saying it's deprecated and then finding this piece of code who is working... Will not put more informations then asked code next time to avoid -1 vote for good answers